# Get resource name from uri

Tags: android, image

I need to pick an image from external app and save in database its name because later I need to get the image using the `getIdentifier()` method. How can I know the image name of the other app starting from uri received?

Edit:

```
Intent pickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); 
pickerIntent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(pickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a URI? URIs can mean a lot of things. Are you trying to get the image of another app starting an activity in your app?

Comment: @napkinsterror Yes, I'm trying to the get the image from my activity using ACTION_PICK.

Comment: Can you post the code? There is possibly an easy way to do this.

Comment: @napkinsterror I posted the code